# Поиск по значению в массиве

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 40
            [NAME] => Пример 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 39
            [NAME] => Пример 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 38
            [NAME] => Пример 3
        )
)
```

Необходимо найти элемент массива по ID и и вывести NAME. Каким образом это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если операция поиска одноразовая, то можно использовать варианты поиска, приведенные в других ответах.
Если же вам нужно обращаться ко множеству элементам по ID, то лучше перевести массив к виду `ID => name`, чего можно добиться простым использованием

```
$data = array_column($array, 'name', 'id');
print $data[39];
```

в случае, если у вас там будет не только `name` и и другие данные, можно дополнительно использовать `array_combine`:

```
$data = array_combine(array_column($array, 'id'), $array);
```

тогда фактически ключи будут заменены на значения `ID`.

Answer (score 2):

`$array` исходный массив, `$searchId` ID который ищите

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item['ID'] == $searchId) {
        echo $item['NAME'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

К примеру можно сделать вот так:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'id' => 40,
        'name' => 'Пример 1'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 39,
        'name' => 'Пример 2'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 38,
        'name' => 'Пример 3'
    )
);

echo $array[array_search(39, array_column($array, 'id'))]['name']; //Пример 2
```